# WSDL import issue in Loadrunner

Tags: performance, rest, soap, loadrunner

I am trying to make a `REST` service in Loadrunner (Version 12.50), for that I am doing the following:

1. create a **web services** script.
2. click **SOATools**
3. click the "**manage services**" button.
4. click the "**import**" button, paste the WSDL's url, and click **Import**.

But the problem is that I get the following Error:

> Cannot get LastHTTPResponse Code:
>   http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL

The specified WSDL may be incompatible with the selected Toolkit.
Try using a different toolkit.

How can I overcome this error?

Comment: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/Load-testing-of-a-REST-API-using-HP-LoadRunner-s-web-custom/ba-p/6174105#.Vg6BuhNVhHw

Comment: the informations provided did not solve my problem, as I try to import the WSDL I got the following error stated above

Comment: REST is web_custom_request(), not WSDL import.

Comment: Is this question still relevant ?